# Convert bitarray to image

Tags: image, matplotlib, cython, bokeh, bitarray

I have large bitarray as a start 100 000 000 bits i.e. 10000x10000.

What is the most feasible and economic way to convert it to scaled down version may be 1000x1000, by preserving best the dot|1 distribution.
I dont know if B&W or gray img will be better.

For the array I'm using the bitarray module and for the image bockeh and as a fallback option matplotlib.

In the past for small imgs I used img.show, but i had to convert the bitarray to numpy, which i dont think is feasible for such large arrays.

BTW. I can use Cython if this will involve looping trough the bitarray

Answer (score 2):

I'd use Datashader for this. If you can get it into an xarray data structure, the easiest way to view it using Datashader + Bokeh is to install hvPlot then import `hvplot.xarray` and do `.hvplot()` as described at https://hvplot.holoviz.org/user_guide/Gridded_Data.html. You can then zoom into the plot and see any region in as much detail as you like.

Comment: xarray is not bit based , right

Comment: True; you'll have to convert it to ints, which will make it bigger, but that still doesn't seem too big to fit on one machine, and easier than trying to write new code to handle it, unless you're going to be doing it a lot. You're asking for feasible, not perfect! :-)

Comment: matplotlib .. img.show() can use np.uint8 ... thanks anyway